# What causes "Role Instances are taking longer than expected" error with Azure SDK 2.4?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-compute-emulator

I am getting the infamous "Role Instances are taking longer than expected" error when trying to start my Azure project with a single Worker Role. It used to work before, it started failing without any apparent reasons between two debug sessions.

I tried to create a brand new solution with a new Azure project and a default Worker Role, that also fails to start.

I have found numerous other SO questions and forum posts discussing this topic, but most of them are outdated and none of their suggestions worked.

I found no relevant message in the Event Logs, the only error message I found was in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\dftmp\EmulatorRuntimeLogs\ErrorRuntime.log`,
it contains lots of lines like this:

```
[00006892:00014472, 2014/10/16, 18:40:45.247, ERROR] Failed to create FSRM quota manager instance.
```

The output for the role in the Compute Emulator displays the following log indefinitely:

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment24(4).MySolution.MyProject.MySolution.MyProject.0
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Aborted
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Aborted
[fabric] Role state Busy
[fabric] Role state Aborted
[fabric] Role state Busy
...
```

Do you have any suggestions what can cause this error with the latest 2.4 version of the Azure SDK?

Comment: FSRM is used for LocalStorage resources, and you implicitly get a LocalStorage resource when you have <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" /> in the CSDEF.  What happens if you get rid of that Diagnostics import?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help, and same log messages.

Comment: Just an update: after long hours of googling/binging, I still haven't found any solution, so I cannot use the developer environment. I am thinking about reinstalling Windows (as other people seem to have done).

Comment: The solution here helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391805/azure-role-not-starting-after-windows-update-10february

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it by removing the Startup Tasks from **ServiceDefinition.csdef**

Comment: This should be marked as answer, at least it has helped me and my collegues a number of times.

Comment: I am using SDK 2.4 and I don't have a startup Tasks in ServiceDefinition.csdef. Is there a solution other than this?

Answer (score 4):

Change the `taskType="background"` in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file

```
<Task taskType="background" executionContext="elevated" commandLine="sample.cmd">
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have a startup task and the following steps worked for me.

- Right click the Azure Cloud service project
- go to the "web" tab.
- In the "Emulator" section choose "Use Full Emulator"
- And in the "Local Development Server" section choose "Use IIS Web Server"

[image]