# azure role not starting after windows update 10February

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-compute-emulator

After installation of windows update on 10th February 2016, the azure roles are not starting in emulator (Full/Express).
The logs show below

```
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.391, FATAL] Role process exited with exit code of -2147024809
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.397, INFO ] Stopping role: deployment25(0).AzureCloudService2.WebRole1_IN_0. Notify: False  Recycle: False  StopTimeout: 30
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.398, IMPRT] State of deployment25(0).AzureCloudService2.WebRole1_IN_0 changed from RoleStateBusy to RoleStateStopping.
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.398, IMPRT] State of deployment25(0).AzureCloudService2.WebRole1_IN_0 changed from RoleStateStopping to RoleStateStopped.
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.398, ERROR] <- WapGetEnvironmentVariable=0x800700cb
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.398, WARN ] (Ignoring) Reading environment variable CleanupFirewallOnRoleRestart failed with HR: 800700cb
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.398, INFO ] The value of cleanupFirewallOnRoleRestart is set to True
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.398, WARN ] Attempting to recover role deployment25(0).AzureCloudService2.WebRole1_IN_0.
[00005748:00006624, 2016/02/14, 12:03:24.399, ERROR] Failed to create FSRM quota manager instance.
```

> **Update 14 Feb 2016**

***Looks like if i use full IIS (not IIS Express) and Full Emulator it works but if i select Express emulator (i can only select IISExpress) it does not****

Comment: Looks like if i use full IIS (not IIS Express) and Full Emulator it works but if i select Express emulator (i can only select IISExpress) it does not

Comment: Edit your question with additional info; don't use comments for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstalling Windows Update KB3126593 solved the problem, but after the Windows update of patch day April 12th 2016, the emulator did not start again. By successively uninstalling the updates, I identified KB3147071 to be the culprit. I reinstalled all the other updates and excluded KB3147071 from further updates and now the emulator works again.

Comment: I reported this to Microsoft and their response was that KB3147071 was the fix to the emulator hang issue, despite clear evidence that it is actually the cause of it. It was a very confusing e-mail exchange. In any case, it seems like the only official guidance I'm going to get will be to upgrade to Azure SDK 2.9 which plays nicely with these updates.

Comment: Update: MS also claimed it should work if you use Full IIS instead of IIS Express.

Comment: I have to defend my answer in this case, as in the description of KB3126593 there is solely stated that other updates are not going to proceed if this one is not installed. Specifically, for me it meant disabling Windows Update completely and waiting for the patch from MS. So there is nothing wrong in what I said before. MS should have contacted me in case the patch was created, they did not do that so far. So I expect that still to come...

Comment: Also, if you search for the description of [KB3147071](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3147071), you will find nothing about Azure Emulator at all. The patch is supposed to be connected to some Oracle connectivity issues.

Comment: Agreed. Ultimately @JanAmbroz's answer is the fix to the February issue and Rob's answer is the fix to the April issue. The April issue should probably be its own question, but at the end of the day you are both right. I agree Jan that KB3147071 ostensibly has nothing to do with Azure, but nevertheless the emulator doesn't work when that update is present.

Answer (score 22):

As I have run into the same issue, I tried to uninstall the updates one by one and came down to the one causing the issue: [KB3126593](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126593).

To verify, I installed all the updates again, except this one, emulator still started properly. After installing the problematic one, emulator stopped working, resumed after uninstalling it again.

I am using quite old Azure Tools v2.6, maybe this is fixed for the newer versions, cannot try this for myself unfortunately.

On my side, both Full and Express emulators were failing, both tried with IIS Express (not using full IIS).

Hope this helps!

> **Update 18 Feb 2016**

I tried to contact Microsoft Azure Support to report this problem, also leading them to this StackOverflow question for more detailed information. They did not seem to care so much, because I don't have an appropriate paid support plan (quite frustrating). If there is anyone who would report this with a valid support plan, I am free to provide any info needed.

> **Update 22 Feb 2016**

Microsoft Azure Support finally started to solve it, it has been reproduced and dispatched to the production team! **The only workaround they presented is to use Full IIS in the meantime.**

Comment: Perfect solution. I had already started un-installing the recent updates one by one. After a frustrating amount of time, I thought of searching for the resolution on Stack Overflow and saw your reply. Thanks Jan. You saved me additional frustration.

Comment: @nikhil Happy to help! I have contacted the Azure Support with the full description of the problem, hope some official solution will come soon!

Comment: Thanks. I am on 2.5 Azure SDK and can not upgrade to latest azure yet. Try on full IIS, it worked for all team members for me.

Comment: Yes. Let's hope it comes out soon. BTW, please note that another symptom of the same issue is that you cannot interact with Azure Storage. An exception “The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure” is thrown.
Removing the same security update KB3126593 will resolve this issue too.

Comment: As I was reading the description of the KB3126593 update, it addresses the way how to search for and load dependent DLL files into a process. This might be quite a serious problem for a lot of older/not-so-conforming applications. Sadly so, the description also says that no other critical/security update will be installed if this one is omitted. So we have to hope...

Answer (score 2):

I use Azure 2.7 and ran into the same problem. After uninstalling Windows Update [KB3126593](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126593) it worked. In the post-installation information section of that update, Microsoft mentions certain error messages that might show up in the event log. I installed the fix again and tried to start a worker (which failed of course), but I did not see any of the described messages. Then I added the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Safe Load Prefixes` with the value 'C:\'. However, I still could not launch the worker role. So I uninstalled the update again and then launching worked. Just to share my experience with my attempt of having both: the Windows update and a working compute emulator.

Comment: According to the link and "**the data of that value is the full path of that trusted location**", it seems that the full location will be needed. If I have some more time today, I will try to determine the exact paths needed.