# Visual Studio 2013 Azure project: Unable to start debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have an Azure MVC project, and when I try to debug it, it hangs at "Starting the role for the application in the Microsoft Azure compute emulator..."

[image: Starting the roles]

After a while, if I try to hit the debug button again, it gives the error "The debugger cannot continue running the process. Unable to start debugging."

[image: Unable to debug]

Any idea what the problem could be? The Azure storage emulator is running when this happens.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing.  My system rebooted over the weekend and now I cannot run anything using Azure SDK 2.6 in the emulator.  I have tried to uninstall and re-install 2.6 without any change.  The only thing that I can get to work it to install Azure SDK 2.8 and then I can create a new project using 2.8 and it runs fine but I can still not run a 2.6 project.  What version of Azure SDK are you using?

Comment: 2.7. Should I install 2.8?

Comment: guess it would depend on the requirements for your project -- I am not able to upgrade to 2.8 at this point since my projects are currently using 2.6 but if I didn't have that restriction or was starting from scratch I would certainly go with 2.8

Comment: you might also check the compute emulator log to see if it is showing anything specific.  It can be found at: C:\Users\csheets\AppData\Local\dftmp_bak\EmulatorRuntimeLogs\EmulatorRuntime.log

Answer (score 0):

There are various things that can cause this and they are not all easy to find! It can be caused by a mismatch between the version of Azure tools referenced in the project and that installed on your PC.

I have had to remove everything related to Azure once and reinstall from scratch!

Another potential problem is if your `WebRole.OnStart` method keeps erroring, in which case, Azure will attempt to continually restart it and that can carry on for a long time. If this happens, it should eventually tell you that the roles are taking too long to start.

There can be problems if you are trying to use IIS instead of IIS Express, I have never got full IIS to work with the Azure debugger.

Try building a simple Azure app that references a default MVC app as a way to make sure it is not caused by mistakes you have made in your code or configuration. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your exact issue or not but I found the following which fixed my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35407737/1399978. Issue is due to a specific Windows security update ([KB3126593](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126593)). Uninstall the update an everything works as it should.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not help a lot of people who have been having similar problems, but I just want to note here that my issues went away when I upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and Azure 2.8. Thanks for all the input, everybody!